# Jquery - Wrap multiple tag child class inside new div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, dom-selection

I want to wrap multiple class inside tag to a new div using jQuery, here is the case html:

```
<div class="article">
    <div>
        <h1>Title 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1>Title 2</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1>Title 3</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img>
    </div>
</div>
```

Result :

```
<div class="article">
    <div class="img-div">
        <div>
            <h1>Title 1</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="img-div">
        <div>
            <h1>Title 2</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="img-div">
        <div>
            <h1>Title 3</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is my attempt jQuery code:

```
$(".article").children("div h1, div img).wrap("<div class='img-div'"></div>);
```

I'm using jQuery `wrap(); wrapAll();` but I just can't get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

If your markup has always the exact same order, you can do a loop like this:

```js
var $set = $('.article').children();    
for(var i=0, len = $set.length; i < len; i+=2){
    $set.slice(i, i+2).wrapAll('<div class="img-div">');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="article">
    <div>
        <h1>Title 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1>Title 2</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1>Title 3</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img>
    </div>
</div>
```